# ul moves on table

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-lists

I have a table with buttons on it, align at left, but when I convert one button to a menu using `<ul>` that moves all the buttons to the right and a bit down... I'm sure that it's cos `<ul>` but, i don't know what to do to delete that format.

I'd try with `list-style: none`, but that didn't work.... any ideas??

This is the code in html:

```
<div id="submenu">
    <div id="subopciones" class="menudesp">

        <ul>
    <table border="0" id="tabla_submenu" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id='celda_submenu'><li><a href="#" id='opcion_submenu' class='opcion_selec'>Blog</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Clasicos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Screencasts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li></td>
        <td id='espacio_submenu'></td>
        <td id='celda_submenu'><a href='prueba.php' id='opcion_submenu' >Gran Formato</a></td>
        <td id='espacio_submenu'></td>
        <td id='celda_submenu'><a href='prueba.php' id='opcion_submenu' >Digital</a></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have CSS declared on this page? Please do add it to your question if you have, it'll assist us in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using css file try:

```
<ul style="margin:0; padding:0">
```

if you are using css, add to the file:

```
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: OH GOD!!!!! thanks!!! is that!!! so easy!!!! and it take me so so so so so loooooooong!!!! thanks you very much Javier!!!!!!!!!!!!